# How to add a record to a specific row forxample to row number 3 in Kendo Ui

Tags: kendo-grid, row

I want to add a record to a specific row for example row 3 or 4, how is it possible?

I have this code which insert the record at last row:

```
var grid = $("#IncidentsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
 grid.dataSource.add(InsertRecord[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dataBound: function (e) {
  var data = this._data;
                for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++) // Loop through all row in kendo grid
                    {
                            var dataItem = data[i];
                            var tr = $("#grid").find("[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']"); 
                             if(i==0) // First Row
                            {
                              tr.children().eq(0).text('Your Message'); // First column 
                            } 
                     }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use insert method instead of add:
`grid.dataSource.insert(index, item);`